org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/pdf
I am trying to get a pdf file from a web service, but it gives me this error

"org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/pdf, type=class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream, genericType=class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream."

My Code
     @GET 
       @Path("/reporte/{id}/{fecha1}/{fecha2}")
       @Produces("application/pdf")
        public Response generarResumenAnualPlanilla(@PathParam("id") Long id, @PathParam("fecha1") String fecha1,@PathParam("fecha2") String fecha2) {
            try { 
                ByteArrayOutputStream reporte = usuarioService.generateUserReport(id, fecha1, fecha2);
    
                // Retornar el archivo generado en la respuesta
                 return Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(reporte.toByteArray()))
                    .type("application/pdf")
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=reporte1.pdf")
                    .build(); 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UsuarioController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return Response.status(CodigoRespuesta.ERROR_INTERNO.getValue()).entity("Error generando el reporte").build();
            }
        } 

     public Respuesta reporte1(Long id, String fechaInicio, String fechaFinal) { 
        try {
            
            Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
            parametros.put("id", id);
            parametros.put("fecha1", fechaInicio);
            parametros.put("fecha2", fechaFinal);
             
            Request request = new Request("UsuarioController/reporte", "/{id}/{fecha1}/{fecha2}", parametros);
            request.get();
     
            if (request.isError()) {
                return new Respuesta(false, request.getError(), "");
            } 
            ByteArrayInputStream reporteStream = (ByteArrayInputStream) request.readEntity(ByteArrayInputStream.class);
            if (reporteStream == null) {
                return new Respuesta(false, "Error obteniendo el archivo PDF.", "");
            }
    
             
            return new Respuesta(true, "", "", "ReportePDF", reporteStream);
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             
            Logger.getLogger(UsuarioService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error con el reporte", ex);
            return new Respuesta(false, "Error con el reporte1.", "reporte1 " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    }


That is expected. Jersey does not provide a default provider for application/pdf, as there is no contract of how the pdf data should be serialized over the net. If you expect just raw bytes, you can use application/octet-stream
